# Ajax POST data in Request Param

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-annotations

I am making a POST request as below :

```
 $.ajax({
     url :"/clientCredentials.json",
     type: "POST",
     data: {
        "clientEmail": email,
        "clientName":clientName,
        "orgName":orgName,
        "logoURL":logoURL,
        "redirectURI":redirectUri
     },
     success: function(response){
        alert("sucess");

     },
     error:function(response){
         alert("something went wrong");
     }
 });
```

On the server,  I am using @RequestParams to get this data.

```
@RequestParam String clientEmail, @RequestParam String clientName, @RequestParam String orgName, @RequestParam String logoURL, @RequestParam String redirectURI
```

I am getting below from from server:

```
{"code":"400","errorMessage":"Required String parameter 'clientEmail' is not present"}
```

If I use @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam to accept this data its working fine.

My question is How can I get this data in Request Parameters? What am I doing wrong?
I have tried Jquery($.get(), $.post()) also. nothing working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could see it in your browser developer tools. On chrome, this is under Network tab.
I cant help u about spring and @RequestParams but jquery.

Comment: Thanks, @Loenix. I got it. somethings wrong in my server configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did small project with latest version of spring boot and jquery and it is working well, and based on investigation I did I found there are 2 factor can make this issue, one from jquery and other one from Spring MVC converters:

1- jquery ajax have contentType parameter

```
contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
```

if this one changed to `application/json` or `application/xml` will change the way it is sending request to server then will make issue to server parsing, but it is default value will send form as `key=value` coma separated and this is OK with `FormHttpMessageConverter` "which is drive us to next point"

2- spring MVC is using `FormHttpMessageConverter` for `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` parsing or converting then you can use `@RequestParam` if this converter changed to other converter like:

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for `'application/json'`

or

`Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter` for `'application/xml'`

so it will expect another request and you can get it using `@RequestBody`

So, you have to check request going from jquery is it form, json, or xml using development tools in your browser, then check you spring code/configuration to be sure that this request is converted by the `FormHttpMessageConverter`, this converter could be changed by the parameters of your `@RequestMapping`.

Answer (score 2):

you cant use $.get with payload(data) but you can use $.post. please add attribute **contentType** in your request parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url :"/clientCredentials.json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        "clientEmail": email,
        "clientName":clientName,
        "orgName":orgName,
        "logoURL":logoURL,
        "redirectURI":redirectUri
    },
    success: function(response){
        alert("sucess");
    },
    error:function(response){
        alert("something went wrong");
    }
});
```